# CSS/HTML Prevent Container Div From Resizing

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent a div from resizing when a webpage is resized. I want the effect that can be found at mmo-champion.com. When you shrink the width the background resizes to the content until a point is reached and then the content shrinks until a minimum width is reached. I understand that part of what I'm looking for is min-width. What controls this?

Comment: It is just `min-width`. Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: for width you can use vw or %, it's responsible

Comment: @UdhayTitus: You mean "responsive", and that's not very useful for specifying a minimum width.

Comment: yes but if you set vw or %, we need not to be set min-width

Comment: @UdhayTitus: Simply setting a relative width is not enough to make your design responsive. If you do nothing else it's just going to be unusably narrow on narrow screens. `min-width` is what you should use if you're not planning on making a responsive website.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I tried this, but it still doesn't give the result I'm looking for.

Comment: ok... @MattiVirkkunen

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen How does one get that left/right margin without having that in there? I think this will help for sure, but now the content div fits to the full sized window. I tried putting this on your last comment, but alas it is gone.

Comment: @TomTomGo: What is it that you want to actually do? If you want fixed width, just use `width`. If you want a maximum width, add `max-width`. If you want to leave a minimum amount of margin while centering the content, put `padding` on your `<body>`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Thank you so much for the help! I actually just plugged in a max-width and it did everything i needed. So with margin:0 auto and max-width it did it. Thanks again. Also do you want to add this as an answer and I'll accept it?